# What is the right expression to say: "doing an activity"?

Tags: expressions

What is the correct expression in order to say:  "you do different activities in the classroom"
Is the verb to do correct here?
What verb do I use with the noun activity?

The sentence I need is a question for a questionnaire.
Here it is:

> "What kind of activities **do you do** in the classroom as a teacher of writing?"

Comment: It's OK to use "do". You can also use "carry out", but it's a bit formal.

Comment: @Khan; the sentence i nees is a question for a questionnaire. Here it is: "what kind of activities do you do in the classroom as a teacher of writing?"

Comment: Is it correct and academic?

Comment: @Hanaa It's very much correct, but in an academic setting I would go with "carry out" or ask "What **kinds** of activities do you plan for your students as a teacher of writing?"  Hopefully the teacher does more than one type of activity, so kind should be plural.

Answer (score 2):

'To do' could be used, but consider using a verb more specific to a teacher "doing" activities in a classroom.  For example, I would use 'perform', 'administer' or 'assign'.

"What kind of activities do you assign in the classroom as a teacher of writing?"

[One technique for writing materials that clearly communicate what you want to say is to use "precise verbs.", http://professionalwritingservices.net/preciseverbs.html](http://professionalwritingservices.net/preciseverbs.html)

Comment: Thank you so much @nicko66. Yes precise verbs and concise ideas are important.